# Change settings value on the fly?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is it possible to change jQuery DataTables settings value on fly. My problem is next,I need to change `sAjaxSource` on fly. Already tried something like this:

```
var oDefault = {
    "bServerSide": true,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 8,
    "sAjaxSource": "my.php?" + "idKat="+aData[3],
    "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ],[ 3, "asc" ]],
    "sDom": '<"top"ir>t<"bottom"pf<"clear">',
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sUrl": "<?php echo $full_path_jezik_2;?>"
    },
    "aoColumns": [
        { "sName": "rb","sWidth": "15%", "sClass": "center","sType": "numeric" },
        { "sName": "chkZaBrisanje","sWidth": "20%", "sClass": "center", "bSortable":false },
        { "sName": "rbPrvaSlika","sWidth": "15%", "sClass": "center","bSortable":false  },
        { "sName": "nazivSlike","sWidth": "50%", "sClass": "center", "sSortDataType": "dom-text"  }
    ]
};

var oST = $.extend( true, {}, oDefault );
oST.sAjaxSource = "my.php?" + "idKat="+aData[3];

alert(oST.sAjaxSource);

if (typeof oTable == 'undefined') {
    oTable = $("#my-table").dataTable(oST);
}
else
{               
    oTable.fnDraw();
}
```

My `aData[3]` is changed on click.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Have you tried

```
 oTable = $("#my-table").dataTable(oST);
 var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
 oSettings.sAjaxSource  = "new value";
```

Comment: Nevermind, it's fnSettings().oFeatures.bProcessing, but it seems fubar if set to false during init.

Comment: @Dan - how do you effect the update? with `table.ajax.reload();` or `table.draw();`. I'm having trouble getting this to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use fnReloadAjax() function, see plug-ins on official datatable site.

Answer (score 1):

**For DataTables 1.10+**:

Use [`ajax.url()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url%28%29) API method as shown below to set the Ajax URL and load the data from the new source immediately:

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: 'data.json'
});

table.ajax.url('newData.json').load();
```

**For DataTables 1.9**:

Use [`fnReloadAjax()`](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnReloadAjax) plugin to reload the table's data from the Ajax source. Please note that this plug-in has been deprecated.