# Update Options on Existing jQuery Object

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I'm using Bootstrap and DataTables in my app and I have a default initializer for tables based on class.  I can just add the class data-table to the table and it gets instantiated with the default values I want.

I'd like to know how to change or update specific options based on a specific table.

```
if ($.fn.dataTable) {
    $('.data-table').dataTable( {
        sDom: "R<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
        sPaginationType: "bootstrap",
        oLanguage: {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ &nbsp; records per page"
        },
        aoColumnDefs: [
            { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
        ]
    });
}
```

All my data tables have a checkbox in the first column so the above removal of sorting works for all of them.  But I'd like to be able to update the `aoColumnDefs` on a table by table basis so I can add other columns that I don't want sorted.

So let's say I have a table: `$('#member-list')`, how do I access this object and update it's datatables options in jQuery?  I can't find any reference or help anywhere.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909206/change-settings-value-on-fly

Comment: I don't see how that helps me.  I tried $('#member-list').fnSettings(); But it throws that it has no method.

Comment: If you do `var memberList = $("#member-list").dataTable(settingsHere);` when creating the dataTable and later do `var settings = memberList.fnSettings();` does it work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can only configure `aoColumnDef` when instantiating the `dataTable` object I decided to take a more elegant approach and use data attributes and an additional function to set the sortable columns.

In my tables I added `data-sort="0, 4, 8"` or whatever specific fields I want sorted.

Then I created a simple function to convert the string value of the data attribute to a numeric array to pass to `aTargets:`.

```
function convertData (string) {
   $array = Array();
   if (string) {
      $items = string.split(',');
      $.each($items, function () {
         $array.push(parseInt(this, 10));
      });
   }
   return $array;
}
```

Now I can simply loop through each `$('.data-table')` and grab the `data-sort` attribute, pass it into `convertData()` to create my array, then pass that into `aTargets` when creating the `dataTable` object.

```
if ($.fn.dataTable) {
   $('.data-table').each(function() {
      $targets = convertData($(this).data('sort'));
      $(this).dataTable({
         sDom: "R<'row'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
         sPaginationType: "bootstrap",
         oLanguage: {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ &nbsp; records per page"
         },
         aoColumnDefs: [
            { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": $targets }
         ]
      });
   });
}
```

Thanks to everyone who tried to help :-)

-V

Answer (score 0):

The **DataTables** plugin has [an alias to access the Settings object](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js#L11672), namely `dataTableSettings`.  I don't know which settings you are attempting to change (or even if they are all writable via this object), but I have verified that one could change, for instance, the sortability of the *nth* column with:

```
`$('#member-list').dataTableSettings.aoColumns[n].bSortable = true;`
```

Comment: I can access the settings object as so:

`$('#member-list').dataTableSettings[0];`

but aoColumnDefs isn't included there, I gather it is only used to apply config variables prior to intantiation of the object.

Comment: I updated with a more concrete example. However, working through this API still may not cover your needs. I'm just not familiar enough with the plugin to answer that for you.

Comment: Perhaps this may work but it's far too much code to do this for dozens of tables.  The data attribute solution I posted is far more versatile and easier to implement.  Appreciate it though!! :-)