# datatable loosing interactivity and styling after reload of new data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, jquery-selectors, datatables

When I initialize datatable for the first time, jQuery selectors like click, higlight rows work fine.

```
    oTable = jQuery('.zebra').dataTable( {
    "bFilter": false,
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "aLengthMenu": [[25], [25]],
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "aaData": ${subscriptions},
    "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
           jQuery(nRow).attr("id",iDisplayIndex);           
           jQuery("#pointSlider", nRow).spinner();
           jQuery(".save").button();
           return nRow;
    },
    "aoColumns": [
                 {"mData":"user_id", "bSortable": false},
                 {"mData":"subscription_id", "bSortable": false},
                 {"mData":"user_name", "bSortable": false},
                 {"mData":"subscription_frequency", "bSortable": false},
                 {"mData":"subscription_price", "bSortable": false},
                 {"mData":"kamuer_first_name", "bSortable": false, "sDefaultContent": null},
                 {"mData":"kamuer_username", "bSortable": false, "sDefaultContent": null},
                 {"mData":"points_user", "bSortable": false, "sDefaultContent": null, 
                     "mRender": function (data, type, full){
                                return '<input id="pointSlider" value= "' + data +'" type="number" min="0" step ="1"/>';
                     },
                     },
                 {"mData":"save", "bSortable": false, "sDefaultContent": null, 
                         "mRender": function (data, type, full){ 
                            return '<img class="save" src="${applicationScope.contextURL}/rsrc/images/results/Green_Check.png" width="20px" title="Save this record" />';   
                         }
                         }
                 ]
});


jQuery(".zebra tbody tr").on('click', function(e) {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('row_selected') ) {
         $(this).removeClass('row_selected');
    }
    else {
        oTable.$('tr.row_selected').removeClass('row_selected');
        var aData = oTable.fnGetData(this);
         $(this).addClass('row_selected');
    }
});

jQuery(".save").on('click', function (e) {
     var userId =   jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).html();
     var subscriptionId = jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).html();
     var points =   jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('#pointSlider').val();

     var baseURL = "<%= request.getContextPath()%>/commission/updateCommission";
     var data = "userId=" + userId + "&subscriptionId=" + subscriptionId + "&points=" +points;
     var URL = baseURL;

    jQuery.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: URL,
          data: data,
          success: alert ("done")

    });

});

jQuery("#subscriptions_search").click(function (e) {
    var startDate = jQuery("#startDate").val();
    var endDate = jQuery("#endDate").val();
    var baseURL = "<%= request.getContextPath()%>/commission/getSubscriptions";
    var data = "startDate=" + startDate + "&endDate=" + endDate;
    var URL = baseURL;

    jQuery.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: URL,
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            refreshTable(data);
        }
    });
});

function fnGetSelected( oTableLocal )
{
    return oTableLocal.$('tr.row_selected');
}

function refreshTable(json)
{

   oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();

   oTable.fnClearTable(this);

   oTable.fnAddData(json.subscriptions);
   oTable.fnDraw();

}
```

The refreshTable gets called when a data change is required by the user. The data loads fine, hpwever the jQuery selectors and interactions with the datable is lost, I've been trying various ways but cannot get to work.

I wonder why a simple jQuery selectors wont work after a data reload? Appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are redefining a new table at this point :

```
table = jQuery(".zebra").dataTable();
```

So you should either get your configuration before calling this.
If you have no other datatables around, you could define your settings as default.

```
$.extend( $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    // your settings
});
```

See https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/defaults.html

Comment: I changed it to reference same table, still has the same problem.
 function refreshTable(json)
 {
  
    oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
     
    oTable.fnClearTable(this);
    
    oTable.fnAddData(json.subscriptions);
    oTable.fnDraw();
    
 }

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post:
 [Change settings value on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909206/change-settings-value-on-fly)

I think you can define your settings as an object and pass it to the dataTable constructor.

Update:

I created a JSFiddle to try it and it works with fake data, just as you wrote it in the first place.
I just created the dataTable element in $(document).ready like this :

```
var oTable;

$(document).ready(function(){
    oTable = jQuery('#mytable').dataTable({
    ...
});
```

Have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/jpreynat/j40jo2dc/5/

Hope this helps.

Comment: No it does not work, the slider on the table is still maintained. However the image which is clicked like a button does not invoke.

Answer (score 0):

Discarded this method and instantiated a new datatable with bDestroy:true. It works.