# Add ajax properties to datatable from jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am trying to modify a datatable on my page in such a way that it attempts to get data via ajax only after a user has logged successfully (if I put the ajax details in at load-time then the connection is refused since the user logs in and a very unprofessional alert is thrown by the browser). Is it possible to add ajax properties to a table after initialisation?

Cheers,

Jack

## Edit

Duplicate of: [Change settings value on the fly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909206/change-settings-value-on-the-fly)

Comment: could you post the code

Comment: Well the only code is an empty datatable with 5 columns at the moment!  Since the 'ajax' section needs to be absent, initially at least

Comment: well you need to post whatever you have at present along with what all you have tried. also if possible you need to create a jsfiddle, http;//jsfiddle.net for quick responses

Comment: The code so far is: myTable = $('#example').DataTable().  The question is basically just 'can you add a property to a datatable post-init.?'